# Directadmin php 7 with MsSQL extension

Tags: sql-server, php-7, directadmin

i have searched a lot on the internet and tried all tutorials.
But i am not able to install Directadmin with PHP7 and MsSql extention

i am using CentOs 7 + Directadmin + php7.0

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score -1):

The following tutorial will walk you through enabling extensions
https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=252

```
Custombuild]# more configure/ap2/configure.php70 
#!/bin/sh
./configure \
    --with-apxs2 \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/lib/php.conf.d \
    --with-curl=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-gd \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --with-gettext \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib \
    -with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
```